# Preg_match - extract id from a string

Tags: php, html, regex

```
<content type='application/x-shockwave-flash' src='https://www.youtube.com/v/f4LxBKN9ank?version=3&amp;f=videos&amp;app=youtube_gdata'/>
```

How could I get only the f4LxBKN9ank number? all my attepts to construct the preg_match failed. Thanks for tips.

EDIT

```
<yt:statistics favoriteCount='0' viewCount='106281'/>

<yt:rating numDislikes='9' numLikes='569'/>
```

How to retrive viewCount and the numDislikes/Likes

Comment: What regex have you tried? That way we can tell you what went wrong and what you should've done (in order for you to learn - yay!)

Comment: use `.explode("/");` better than using a regex

Comment: Could you mark an answer as right?

Answer (score 2):

Not that cool but regular expression are not that "fast". str_replace is much faster. BTW: "parse_url" rocks: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php

```
<?php 

$data = str_replace(array("path" => "/v/"),array(''),parse_url('https://www.youtube.com/v/f4LxBKN9ankversion=3&amp;f=videos&amp;app=youtbe_gdata'));

var_dump($data['path']);
// string 'f4LxBKN9ank' (length=11)
```

Comment: Thanks but I need a simpler one. Still might be usefull in the future.

Comment: Hehe, so show me the more "simple" way =))) 3 lines sounds good to me.

Comment: Answe below I need a preg_match only. Not a parse, you can make 2 more  preg_matches updated my post.

Comment: Ha, here you are. 1 line :P

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
<?php
preg_match('#www\.youtube\.com\/v\/([\w\-]+)\?#', $string, $match);

$id = $match[1];
echo $id;
```

For your other question, I strongly discourage you to use a regex for parsing HTML/XML.
You should go for something like [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) or [DOM](http://php.net/domdocument).

Comment: Works great but I need a handler on sign - _ (and its random and both could occur) cause some video ids got that

Comment: Yeah, sure! I've updated my answer. Add `\-`, `\w` includes the underscore

Comment: Ansewr is #www\.youtube\.com\/v\/([\w-_]+)#  Thanks

Comment: I edited my question need 2 more simple preg_matches. Could you help? I can approve the answer in 3 min anyway

Comment: There're no needs to escape the slashes as you're using `#` as delimiter.